# Get count of events pr. month, including zero, where event is a specific one - 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a result that contains all months within the period with a count of how many events pr. month. This should include zero (0) if no events found.

To do this I have created a table "log_dates" that contains all dates. This table only contains a "date" column.

The table "log_events" only contains events for the days where there is an event. One row in the table is one event. A single event can't contain multiple events - so we need to count the event rows to get the result. This table contains id, date and eventtype_id columns.

The problem is that as soon as I add "**AND events.eventtype_id='3'**" to the query below, the output does **not** contain months with zero events in them:

```
SELECT dates.date
     , IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) AS sum 
  FROM log_events AS events 
  LEFT 
  JOIN log_dates AS dates 
    ON (DATE(events.date)=dates.date) 
 WHERE (dates.date BETWEEN DATE('2010-04-30') AND DATE('2014-09-14')) 
   AND events.eventtype_id='3' 
 GROUP  
    BY YEAR(dates.date)
     , MONTH(dates.date) 
 ORDER 
    BY dates.date ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example. Feel free to adapt it to your needs. Note that range queries can use indexes whereas functions (like DATE()) cannot, so best avoided if possible...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS log_events;

 CREATE TABLE log_events(event_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,date DATE NOT NULL,eventtype_id INT NOT NULL);

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS log_dates;

 CREATE TABLE log_dates (date DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

 INSERT INTO log_events VALUES 
 (1,'2014-01-01',1),
 (2,'2014-01-03',3),
 (3,'2014-01-05',3),
 (4,'2014-01-05',2),
 (5,'2014-01-05',3);

 INSERT INTO log_dates VALUES 
 ('2014-01-01'),
 ('2014-01-02'),
 ('2014-01-03'),
 ('2014-01-04'),
 ('2014-01-05'),
 ('2014-01-06'),
 ('2014-01-07');

 SELECT d.*
      , COALESCE(COUNT(e.event_id),0)
   FROM log_dates d
   LEFT
   JOIN log_events e
     ON e.date = d.date
    AND e.eventtype_id = 3
  WHERE d.date BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
  GROUP 
     BY d.date;

+------------+-------------------------------+
| date       | COALESCE(COUNT(e.event_id),0) |
+------------+-------------------------------+
| 2014-01-01 |                             0 |
| 2014-01-02 |                             0 |
| 2014-01-03 |                             1 |
| 2014-01-04 |                             0 |
| 2014-01-05 |                             2 |
| 2014-01-06 |                             0 |
| 2014-01-07 |                             0 |
+------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly it is the same result :-( The rows with zero is not returned.

Comment: The output should be pr. month. Here is a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9235d/1/0   Where is "May".

Comment: Follow my template, but substitute DATE_FORMAT(d.date,'%Y%m') for date. I'd rather not spell out the whole solution.

Comment: When I first tried your solution I could not get it to work. But now it works! THANK you so much. This one query has taken me several days to get finished. A small note to others is that in your solution the "event_id" should be "eventtype_id".

Comment: No, my query is correct for my schema. Of course your schema may be different!